# Arrow operator and vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I've been attempting to reassign a particular vector element to a new value and received a error from the compiler, and I'm not sure I understand it. So I believed that you could reassign a single vector element in the same way you could reassign an array's element.

```
std::vector<int> myVector[10];

myVector[5] = 6;
```

Or you could alternatively use the built in '.at' to access the vector with bounds checking. When I was writing some trivial code just to understand some concepts better I ran across a peculiar situation.

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<int> test[10];

    test[3] = 5;

    if (test[3] != 6) 
    {
        std::cout << "It works!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now this piece of code flags an error saying that the assignment operator '=' and the logical operator '!=' doesn't match based on these operands. Now if I use the arrow operator '->' the code works just fine. Which is good, but I thought, perhaps mistakenly, that the arrow operator was used when dereferencing a pointer-to-object. I attempted to google these results, but perhaps due to the very rudimentary nature of it, I couldn't find much on the topic. Although, I would like to mention on a few sites with "c++ tutorials" I did see that they used the assignment operator without dereferencing the vector. Now this happens in both Visual Studios 2017 as well as the most recent version of Code::Blocks. Was I wrong? Do you actually need to utilize the arrow operator? Or am I missing something even more basic?

Comment: How did you "use the arrow operator" in `test[3] = 5;` ?

Comment: @M.M The only method that I could get to work for me was:
    "test->at(3);"
Also, I noticed that you put the area where I called it the arrow operator in quotations. Is that not the correct term for it in c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created an array of 10 vectors, not a vector of 10 elements. A vector is is ultimately a class type, so you need to initialize it via a constructor:

```
std::vector<int> test(10);
```

The way you did it originally, meant you tried to assign the value 5 for the vector at index 3. Vectors don't support being assigned numbers, so that's what the error is about.

Comment: My lord do I feel silly. Just ignore me, I'm going to shrivel up in a corner and think about my life decisions. Thank you very much for correcting my ignorance.

Comment: @AaronMcAnally - It happens. We all had to learn how things work in C++, once. And if you plan to delve into C++ further, this won't be the last time you have a moment like that. C++ veterans still get them ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring an array of vectors rather than one vector of some initial length. Use the following instead of your declaration:

```
std::vector<int> myVector(10);
```

Comment: Now that it's pointed out I feel ridiculous, thank you very much for your timely response. Now, I can atleast get back to studying.

Comment: @AaronMcAnally I did the same thanks for asking this question.